# Populate datagridview by passing column and row name

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the DataGridView below and I need to check the cell according to the receipt of some files, I am looking for the best way to do this and I thought it would be possible to insert a value in the cell by the name of the column and the name of the row

[image]

The positions are

[image]

If I wanted to mark the position 0,0 I would look for **31 - SEGUROS** (Name of the column) and **01** (Name of row) and then it would be marked the cell 0,0

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView has a CurrentCell property that includes a RowIndex and ColumnIndex.

There is also the CellEnter event where the DataGridViewCellEventArgs includes a RowIndex and ColumnIndex.

There is the Rows and Columns properties that have overloads to accept an index or a name.  However, there is a difference between the name of a column and the column heading.  In your case "**31 - SEGUROS**" is heading of the column and not its name.  Each Column object has a HeaderText property.

If a column or row is not selected, its index will be -1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for row and column indexing? I read your question three times and still it looks like it...

VB.NET:

```
    Dim MyVal = 1234
    Dim ColIdx = 5
    Dim RowIdx = 10
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows(RowIdx).Cells(ColIdx).Value = MyVal
```

C#:

```
    Dynamic MyVal = 1234;
    Dynamic ColIdx = 5;
    Dynamic RowIdx = 10;
    this.DataGridView1.Rows(RowIdx).Cells(ColIdx).Value = MyVal;
```

You can also address the rows and cells by their names, simply putting their name into double quotes.

To get column index by name of a column (not text in the heading):

VB.NET:

```
Private Function GetColIdx(MyStringName As String)
    Dim ColIdx As Int16
    For ic = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim dc As DataGridViewColumn = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(ic)
        If dc.Name = MyStringName Then
            ColIdx = ic
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return ColIdx
End Function
```

C#:

```
Private Object GetColIdx(String MyStringName)
{
    Int16 ColIdx = default(Int16);
    For (ic = 0; ic <= this.DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; ic++) {
        DataGridViewColumn dc = this.DataGridView1.Rows(ic);
        If (dc.Name == MyStringName) {
            ColIdx = ic;
            break; 
        }
    }
    Return ColIdx;
}
```

To get column index, you then simply call (C#) the function with the **name** of the column:

```
GetColIdx("SEGUROS")
```

Similar function can get row by name. Though it is very uncommon to use row names, it is possible. It can also be modified to match text in the heading, but names are more safe.